# When should a program inform the user that it cannot open a file?

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream, file-read

I have got a program that creates an object and uses a function of this object that takes two filenames and reads data from them and sets its value.

Should the object check if the `ifstream` is open by itself or should it be done in the `main` function, that firstly tries to create a pair of `ifstream` values and passes them to this function? There is a sketch:

```
int main() {

    Myclass *m = new Myclass();

    string file1, file2;
    …initialize file1, file2…

    Myclass.readFromFiles(file1, file2);

    delete m;
}
```

in my class:

```
void readFromFiles(const string &file1, const string &file2) {
    std::ifstream infile1(file1);
    if (!infile1.is_open()) {  throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file"); }
    infile1 >> value;

    std::ifstream infile2(file2);
    if (!infile2.is_open()) {  throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file"); }
    infile2 >> value2 >> value3;
}
```

Or rather

```
std::ifstream open_file(std::string filename) {
    std::ifstream infile(posesFilename);
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
    }
    else
        return infile;
}

int main() {

    Myclass *m = new Myclass();

    string file1, file2;
    …initialize file1, file2…
    try{
        std::ifstream f1 = open_file(file1);
        std::ifstream f2 = open_file(file2);

        Myclass.readFromFiles(f1, f2);
    }catch (runtime_error e){
       cout<< e.what() <<endl;
    }

    delete m;
}
```

in my class:

```
void readFromFiles(std::ifstream &f1, std::ifstream &f2)
    f1 >> value;
    f2 >> value2 >> value3;
}
```

Comment: Side note: Do not use `new`, just have objects without dynamically allocation

Comment: First option is better but not perfect though.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking ok thanks for note. even the main is simple and i use delete later on?

Comment: Alternately, the second option could be considered better.  Change `readFromFiles(...)` to accept `istream&` instead of `ifstream&`, and you could test your `readFromFiles(...)` with a string buffer.

Comment: _"test your readFromFiles(...) with a string buffer"_ what do you mean by this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `std::stringstream`.  You could build a `std::stringstream` object containing test data in a unit test function, and pass the `std::stringstream` object to your `readFromFiles( )` as the input stream.

Comment: `Myclass.readFromFiles(` should be `m->readFromFiles(`, unless the `readFromFiles` method is declared as static.

Comment: In your second example, the variables `f1` and `f2` are out of scope when you try to use them, aren't they?

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler yeah sorry, I have changed this on my computer and forgot to fix it here

Answer (score 2):

In the former case, you are making the life easier for the caller of the function.  They only need to pass two filenames to your method.  The method is responsible for opening and closing the files.  If you call this method from more than one location, you've reduced the amount of duplicate code.  It is also not very flexible: if the caller has the `ifstream&` references, but doesn't have the names of the files, they can't call your `readFromFiles(filename1, filename2)` method.

In the latter case, the caller can call your `readFromFiles()` whether they have `ifstream&` references or by opening the files first if they just have the filenames.  Also, the method can be made more flexible.  Changing the expected arguments to `istream&` instead of `ifstream&` would allow you to use any input stream as sources to read the data from.  As an example, a unit test could be created where `std:strstream` are constructed, and passed to your read data method.

For the best of both worlds, provide both methods:

```
void readFromFiles(const string &file1, const string &file2) {
    std:ifstream f1(file1);
    if (!f1.is_open()) {  throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file"); }
    std:ifstream f2(file2);
    if (!f2.is_open()) {  throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file"); }
    readFromFiles(f1, f2);
}

void readFromFiles(std:istream& f1, std:istream& f2) {
   // ...
}
```

You've provided both convenience and flexibility for the caller.  If the caller needs to know which of the two files failed to open (for instance, maybe they want to fallback on "file1_default" if "file1" isn't present, and fallback on "file2_default" if "file2" isn't present), they can have complete control over opening the file and any reporting of the failure to open.

Comment: good idea! And is it okey that class checks it by its own and doesnt expect to get an ifstream that is expected to be proper?

Comment: An `ifstream` __is__ an `istream`.  There is no issue passing an `ifstream` to a function that expects an `istream&`.  This is standard C++ inheritance at work.

Comment: yeah, but you wrote _void readFromFiles(const string &file1, const string &file2) {_ so there my class would check if the file exist and throw exception otherwise. Is it okey that class does such a thing instead of expecting something that is already checked for example istream?

Comment: If you are passing filenames to a method, then that method is responsible for opening the files, and yes, it should check whether or not it was able to open the files, before calling the second method.  The second method takes in the `istream&`, which doesn't have the `is_open` method, and therefore cannot call that method; it must rely on being passed an opened stream.